# How to make my blog available to other website using RSS feed?

Tags: plugins

I do blogging a lot. I run my own website - www.tune2wizard.com I want my blogs to be published in other websites like codeproject - articles etc. However, I don't know how to create the RSS link for my website articles. I use word press on my website. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress does this automatically for you in a fairly basic manner. http://www.tune2wizard.com/feed/ this is a feed of all your articles, if you want further customization you'll need to search for a plugin or find some tutorials on how to manipulate the RSS feeds.

Comment: so, for example,  I have given this link to the codeproject,  whenever I will update any blogs or add a new blog, the update should be available automatically to the code project. Is my understanding correct? For the existing ones, the RSS feed will not work, if they aren't changed.

Comment: Correct. If you want a feed from a specific category, you can also use the `/feed/` at the end of your category URL as well: http://www.tune2wizard.com/category/cc-coders/kernelprogramming/feed/ or http://www.tune2wizard.com/category/embedded-linux/feed/